# SQL coding style: commas

Tags: sql, coding-style

Which of these SQL coding styles is better and why?

**Comma first:**

```
SELECT Name
    , Email
    , Phone
FROM Contact
```

**Comma last:**

```
SELECT Name,
    Email,
    Phone
FROM Contact
```

Comment: I prefer the second one. But frankly you usually embed your code in another language, follow its conventions and the constraints of the query building procedure.

Comment: Downvoters, please give your reasons. I'm sure I'm not the only one with this question.

Comment: I guess the downvoters (I wasn't one) thought this was not going to be constructive (read the FAQ). It can be discussed, I'm not sure.

Comment: I use only the first version for the languages I use (R, SQL, Perl)., even if Joe Celko, the SQL Guru, does not recommend in his book about SQL-Style. Here are the rationales: 1) you have a better control if there is a missing comma, 2) if you want copy the whole variable list without comma you can use rectangular copy by. This is not possible if you have the commas at the end. 3) it gives a structure to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid, do what you or your shop does **consistently**.  I prefer method 2.  Visually at first glance the first one appears to be missing a comma, only after you look some more do you notice that its fine.  Readability for others is key.

Answer (score 2):

A query from some work I am working on:

```
    SELECT TOP 1000 [Id]
      ,[ProductCode]
      ,[Month]
      ,[Year]
      ,[SalesVolume]
  FROM [VeryBigCorp].[dbo].[MonthlySales]
```

I would have to say that the above is a very neat way of doing it, less margin for error.

Comment: This way you know that your not missing a comma because it becomes obvious if you have.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of preference. Personally, I prefer the second example, but there's no benefit to using one over the other.

In the first example, you need to remove the leading comma for the first column, and in the second example you need to remove the trailing comma from the last column.